# Какими дополнениями на js/php можно получить редактируемую таблицу?

Tags: php, javascript

Какими современными средствами пользоваться, чтобы получить редактируемую таблицу?

Что-то на вроде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В силу ряда причин функционал yii не подходит. Bootstrap, наверно, избыточен.

Comment: вообще это yii-x-editable, x-editable есть и [сам по себе](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/)

Comment: Встройте гугл-док ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите компонент DataTables Editor. Сам на Javascript, разные варианты бек-енда, в т.ч. PHP.

https://editor.datatables.net/